# How to fix IE 9 issue using AngularJs tooltip?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I am using angularJs character counter tooltip its working good in all latest browser but with IE 9 there is an issue when user exceed the limit 1024 it should restrict user to type any more but its not happening in IE 9 version of internet explorer.

Any work around for IE 9 ?

main.html

```
<textarea rows="2" class="form-control" id="name"
            ng-model="processDTO.processLongName"
            placeholder="Business Process Name" maxlength="1024" name="processName"
            required
            data-tooltip-html-unsafe="<div>{{1024 - processDTO.processLongName.length}} characters left</div>"
            tooltip-trigger="{{{true: 'focus', false: 'never'}[processDTO.processLongName.length >= 0 || processDTO.processLongName.length == null ]}}"
            tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-class="bluefill">
        </textarea>
```

Comment: Why are people still using IE9, recommend IE11 (if they want to stick to IE due to certain reasons) or other browsers?

Comment: Qa is still supporting some applications that were build for IE 9 so they found this defect.

Comment: issue is with maxlength attribute that is not supported in IE 9

Comment: I [understand that maxlength for textarea is not supported for IE9](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/03-maxlength.html) but what is that specific element/library/component that was written specifically for IE9 and won't work on IE10 or 11? Architecturally there is not much different in IE9 or IE10 or IE11. Considering IE9 works only on Windows 7 and it also supports latest IE i.e. IE11 you should inform QA to update their specs/checklist accordingly. IE9 was release 5 years ago and IE11 itself 2.5 years ago, nowdays other browsers are releasing updates every couple of weeks.

Comment: Thanks! I already responded to them its not a valid defect.